# Cannot activate "Workflows can use app permissions" Site Feature in Sharepoint Foundation 2019

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, content-approval, 2019, exception

I am trying to create a workflow (According to the "Approval - Sharepoint 2010" template) and to activate "Enable Content Approval" in it, this works fine, but it doesn`t do anything.

Some research resulted in the site feature "Workflows can use app permissions" to be nessessary to use this feature.

So I go to the site that contains the library, go to "Site settings", "Manage site features", look for the feature and click the Activate-button.

Doing that results in this error message

[image: An unexpected error has occured.]

Using the Correlation ID I was able to find this stack trace, which seems to maybe explain why it does not work:

```
Unexpected Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.NotConnectedException:
Exception of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.NotConnectedException' was thrown.

at Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.SPAppOnlyPolicyManagerFeatureReceiver.ConfigureAppOnlyPolicy(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties, Boolean isAppOnly)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.DoActivationCallout(Boolean fActivate, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean fMarkOnly, Boolean fIgnoreMissing, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivator.ActivateFeature(Guid featid, Int32 compatibilityLevel, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivatorItem.ToggleFeatureActivation()
at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.FeatureActivatorItem.BtnActivateFeature_Click(Object objSender, EventArgs evtargs)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Sadly I do not know what this means, and I couldn`t find anything on Google.

I hope someone can explain what this means, or maybe even tell me, how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have not setup or completely configured the Workflow Manager.  The below link is for SP2013, but it will work for SP2019.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server

Comment: This looks correct, I will try this solution on monday and will then return with an answer, thank you

Comment: We haven´t actually managed to install the workflow manager, we are now looking for a sharepoint-external solution. I sadly don´t know if this answer was helpful, but it was the most helpful answer, which is why I accept this answer now.